# Pivot without aggregate

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot-table, pivot-without-aggregate

Please help me with this. 
I have the data as this:

```
ID          Name          TotalCost     
----   ----------------  ----------  
1      Wash, Dry & Fold     175.00    
2      Hand Wash and Fold   275.00
3      Pressing Only        25.00   
4     Hand Wash and Fold    205.00
5     Dry Clean             395.00
6     Pressing Only         100.00
```

I would like to display my table like this:
Is this possible using PIVOT without Agrregate?

```
ID     Wash, Dry & Fold    Hand Wash and Fold  Pressing Only    Dry Clean 
----   ----------------   -----------------    --------------   -----------
1         175.00    
2                              275.00
3                                                                25.00   
4                              205.00
5                                                               395.00
6                                                 100.00
```

Thank you.

Comment: You will still use an aggregate function, it's required for pivot - you'll need to use `sum()`.  Have you tried to write the query to get the result?

Comment: @bluefeet I tried, It sum each column. I need to display the table like the example above. Is there anything way to display like that?

Comment: Please change your title...SUM is an Aggregate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from 
(
  select ID, Name, TotalCost
  from Table
) src
pivot
(
  sum(TotalCost)
  for Name in ('Wash, Dry & Fold','Hand Wash and Fold','Pressing Only','Dry Clean' )
) piv;
```

Comment: It sum each column. I need to display the table like the example above. Is there anything way to display like that without the aggregate function? Thank you.

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: Thanks @Webdev, I got it. Just don't use the select all.